# How to get integer from string returned as ajax response

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that sends the data to my web service which in turn returns the status of POST with an integer giving details about the number of records updated. I want to filter the integer from the returned string. But the integer is concatinated with the status while returning as below:

```
     return "Saved"+totalrowsupdated.ToString();
```

How can I get those separated? i want to show the integer in the page somewhere. Is it possible? or What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're forced to return a simple string, you can always used regular expressions to parse out the integer, something like:

```
var updated = result.match(/\d/);
```

However this is a bit gross, if you want to return more information than just a simple status,  a JSON result is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use something like: `var num = parseInt(response.replace("Saved", ''), 10);`?